# Convert character vector of times into proper format and bin in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

So I have a vector which looks as follows:

```
TIME
7:16:00
16:00:00
17:35:00
16:10:00
5:25:00
18:00:00
```

These are read into R as character strings. My goal is to bin them into 4 groups

**GROUPS**

- Bin 1: 12:01am - 6:00am
- Bin 2: 6:01am  - 12:00pm
- Bin 3: 12:01pm - 6:00pm
- Bin 4: 6:01pm  - 12:00am

How exactly do I go about doing this? Preference is to use lubridate

Final Output:

```
TIME        Bin
7:16:00     Bin 2: 6:01am  - 12:00pm
16:00:00    Bin 3: 12:01pm - 6:00pm
17:35:00    Bin 3: 12:01pm - 6:00pm
16:10:00    Bin 3: 12:01pm - 6:00pm
5:25:00     Bin 1: 12:01am - 6:00am
18:00:00    Bin 3: 12:01pm - 6:00pm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one possibility using `lubridate` and `tidyverse`

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(TIME = 
             c("7:16:00", "16:00:00",
               "17:35:00", "16:10:00",
               "5:25:00", "18:00:00")
)

df %>%
  mutate(Bin = paste("Bin ", ceiling((hour(hms(TIME) + minute(hms(TIME)) / 60) / 6)))

      TIME    Bin
1  7:16:00 Bin  2
2 16:00:00 Bin  3
3 17:35:00 Bin  3
4 16:10:00 Bin  3
5  5:25:00 Bin  1
6 18:00:00 Bin  3
```

Here is a base R alternative:

```
df$h <- as.numeric(sub("(\\d+):.*", "\\1", df$TIME))
df$m <- as.numeric(sub(".*:(\\d+):.*", "\\1", df$TIME)) 
df$Bin <- paste("Bin", ceiling((df$h + df$m / 60) / 6))
```

Comment: hm this works, but lubridate/tidyverse is still prefered.

Comment: Personally, I liked your old answer. But this one is good too.

Comment: Awesome this is it! Thank you! and yeah, @IanCampbell makes a point im sure folks wanna see both.

Comment: @IanCampbell thanks :). Personally, I try to use base R alternatives instead of `lubridate`.